# Corner-aligned dashed lines in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

Does anyone know how to create corner-aligned dashed lines in Inkscape?
I am looking for a similar feature that exists in Adobe Illustrator (see
http://tv.adobe.com/watch/learn-illustrator-cs5/creating-corneraligned-dashed-lines/)
I am not able to find this feature or a workaround in Inkscape version 0.91.

Thank you in advance,

Andries

[image]

Comment: Welcome on GD! Have you ever tried to work on the **dash offset**? See [here](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Attributes-Stroke.html) and tell us something about your efforts!

Comment: There is not a simple way to obtain what you are looking for!

Answer (score 1):

The SVG working group proposed the property [stroke-dashcorner](https://svgwg.org/specs/strokes/#StrokeDashcornerProperty) in their draft for upcoming SVG versions. The property does what you want, but is (as far as I know) not supported by any SVG renderer yet. Maybe in the future ...

At the moment, I only see two options:

1. Play with the dash offset (as Paolo suggested).
2. Draw the corner dashes manually.